# How prevalent are gastrointestinal parasites in gay men?

Tags: gastroenterology

I was doing some research on gay health outcomes and came across some very old studies with very high prevalence rates for gastrointestinal parasites among gay men. (https://jcm.asm.org/content/24/4/684) Now, these are very old studies, so I take the incidence rate with a bit of salt, but I’m wondering if there’s any more recent research about this?

Comment: What does MSM stand for?

Comment: Men who have sex with men.

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. Have you been unable to find more recent research on this question? Where did you look? A brief search on my part seems to show that this was a hot research topic in the 1980s but not so much since then.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried looking but it ended up like your search.